# Best practice for naming and using table and view entity in java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, naming-conventions

I am developing a software via `JavaFX`, using MVC design pattern.
In javaFX to sync view with data I use property fields(like `StringProperty`, `IntegerProperty`, ...) and `ObservableList`collection.
Also I am using `JPA` library.
Consider I have two `tables` in DB, One is city and another is province.
`province to city` has one to many `relationship`.

**First question:**

If I create a view with all data from city and province, what should be the name of that view?
It should be city_vm?
Or I should change table names to citybase and provincebase or something like this? and after that change the view name to city?

**Second question :**

I want to map all of them into real entities, I want to map the tables(city and province tables) for insertion data and use view entity for selections and displaying data.
Also note that I have a separate class for each of them(additional from their entity class) to achieve advantage of property fields(like `StringProperty`, `IntegerProperty`, .... )

This is City class ( Not mapped, with Property fields)

```
public class City {

    private int city_id;
    private StringProperty name;
    private FloatProperty asl_ft;
    private FloatProperty asl_mt;
    private FloatProperty sdb_fh;
    private FloatProperty sdb_cs;
    private FloatProperty swd_fh;
    private FloatProperty swd_cs;
    private FloatProperty wdb_fh;
    private FloatProperty wdb_cs;

    private ProvinceEntity province;

    public City(String name, Float asl_ft, Float asl_mt, Float sdb_fh,
            Float sdb_cs, Float swd_fh,
            Float swd_cs, Float wdb_fh, Float wdb_cs) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.asl_ft = new SimpleFloatProperty(asl_ft);
        this.asl_mt = new SimpleFloatProperty(asl_mt);
        this.sdb_fh = new SimpleFloatProperty(sdb_fh);
        this.sdb_cs = new SimpleFloatProperty(sdb_cs);
        this.swd_fh = new SimpleFloatProperty(swd_fh);
        this.swd_cs = new SimpleFloatProperty(swd_cs);
        this.wdb_fh = new SimpleFloatProperty(wdb_fh);
        this.wdb_cs = new SimpleFloatProperty(wdb_cs);
    }

    public City() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.getValue().toString();
    }

    public StringProperty nameStringProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public FloatProperty asl_ft_FloatProperty() {
        return asl_ft;
    }

    public FloatProperty asl_mt_FloatProperty() {
        return asl_mt;
    }

    public FloatProperty sdb_fh_FloatProperty() {
        return sdb_fh;
    }

    public FloatProperty sdb_cs_FloatProperty() {
        return sdb_cs;
    }

    public FloatProperty swd_fh_FloatProperty() {
        return swd_fh;
    }

    public FloatProperty swd_cs_FloatProperty() {
        return swd_cs;
    }

    public FloatProperty wdb_fh_FloatProperty() {
        return wdb_fh;
    }

    public FloatProperty wdb_cs_FloatProperty() {
        return wdb_cs;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    public Float getAslFT() {
        return asl_ft.get();
    }

    public Float getAslMT() {
        return asl_mt.get();
    }

    public Float getSdbFH() {
        return sdb_fh.get();
    }

    public Float getSdbCS() {
        return sdb_cs.get();
    }

    public Float getSwdFH() {
        return swd_fh.get();
    }

    public Float getSwdCS() {
        return swd_cs.get();
    }

    public Float getWdbFH() {
        return wdb_fh.get();
    }

    public Float getWdbCS() {
        return wdb_cs.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public void setAsl_ft(Float asl_ft) {
        this.asl_ft.set(asl_ft);
    }

    public void setAsl_mt(Float asl_mt) {
        this.asl_mt.set(asl_mt);
    }

    public void setSdb_fh(Float sdb_fh) {
        this.sdb_fh.set(sdb_fh);
    }

    public void setSdb_cs(Float sdb_cs) {
        this.sdb_cs.set(sdb_cs);
    }

    public void setSwd_fh(Float swd_fh) {
        this.swd_fh.set(swd_fh);
    }

    public void setSwd_cs(Float swd_cs) {
        this.swd_cs.set(swd_cs);
    }

    public void setWdb_fh(Float wdb_fh) {
        this.wdb_fh.set(wdb_fh);
    }

    public void setWdb_cs(Float wdb_cs) {
        this.wdb_cs.set(wdb_cs);
    }
}
```

And here its `entity` class named CityEntity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class CityEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "city_id", nullable = false)
    private int city_id;
    @Column(name = "city_sn", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "asl_ft", nullable = false)
    private Float asl_ft;
    @Column(name = "asl_mt", nullable = false)
    private Float asl_mt;
    @Column(name = "sdb_fh", nullable = false)
    private Float sdb_fh;
    @Column(name = "sdb_cs", nullable = false)
    private Float sdb_cs;
    @Column(name = "swb_fh", nullable = false)
    private Float swb_fh;
    @Column(name = "swb_cs", nullable = false)
    private Float swb_cs;
    @Column(name = "wdb_fh", nullable = false)
    private Float wdb_fh;
    @Column(name = "wdb_cs", nullable = false)
    private Float wdb_cs;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_province$city")
    private ProvinceEntity province;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Float getAslFT() {
        return asl_ft;
    }

    public Float getAslMT() {
        return asl_mt;
    }

    public Float getSdbFH() {
        return sdb_fh;
    }

    public Float getSdbCS() {
        return sdb_cs;
    }

    public Float getSwbFH() {
        return swb_fh;
    }

    public Float getSwbCS() {
        return swb_cs;
    }

    public Float getWdbFH() {
        return wdb_fh;
    }

    public Float getWdbCS() {
        return wdb_cs;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAsl_ft(Float asl_ft) {
        this.asl_ft = asl_ft;
    }

    public void setAsl_mt(Float asl_mt) {
        this.asl_mt = asl_mt;
    }

    public void setSdb_fh(Float sdb_fh) {
        this.sdb_fh = sdb_fh;
    }

    public void setSdb_cs(Float sdb_cs) {
        this.sdb_cs = sdb_cs;
    }

    public void setSwb_fh(Float swd_fh) {
        this.swb_fh = swd_fh;
    }

    public void setSwb_cs(Float swd_cs) {
        this.swb_cs = swd_cs;
    }

    public void setWdb_fh(Float wdb_fh) {
        this.wdb_fh = wdb_fh;
    }

    public void setWdb_cs(Float wdb_cs) {
        this.wdb_cs = wdb_cs;
    }
}
```

From the start it should be three class for each entity.
One to use advantage of property fields.( City in this example),one for view to select data(combination of city and province),and the last one for table(in this example the city table)

Now If I want to map the city table and city view in my project and use it; What is the best practice for naming convention in `Java` and `Mysql`.

Comment: as to naming, you must follow java naming conventions - otherwise your code is hard to read, at least for others, but after while of getting accustomed to it, for you as well ;) The other part is primarily opinion - in your shoes I would with fewer classes and get a firm grip on fx before making it complicated, but that's only my personal preference :)

Comment: The best practices for naming have always been the same. Use names that make code easy to understand and read. For Java specifically, follow Java's naming convention guidelines.  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Do not use abreviations in variable/type names, unless they are well understood by everyone (e.g. XML). Except for `city_id` none of your field names can be understood by someone reading the code the first time which is a bad idea. (In addition to `_` as part of the name of variables violating the java naming conventions).